# Make the switch statement elegant

Tags: javascript, ajax, switch-statement, javascript-objects, object-literal

I think that using a switch statement is too much code, I saw on some websites that are better ways to simplify switch statement or even convert to an object literal like some examples that show on this website linked below

[Rewriting Javascript: Replacing the Switch Statement](https://medium.com/chrisburgin/rewriting-javascript-replacing-the-switch-statement-cfff707cf045)

[Using object literals and map method instead of the old switch statement](https://www.nikpro.com.au/using-object-literals-and-map-method-instead-of-the-old-switch-statement/)

I tried to convert the switch statement and here is an example of what used. 
Both of them are not working as it should, they display the wrong list of cities when the country is selected. England is displaying scotland-cities.html and so on.

Ex: 1

```
const city = (county) => ({

        "England": $('#uk_states').load('england-cities.html'),
        "Scotland": $('#uk_states').load('scotland-cities.html'),
        //...

    })[county]

let county = city([$('#Uk_Cities option:selected').text()]);
```

Ex: 2

```
let city = {
            "England": {
                "file": $('#uk_states').load('england-cities.html'),
                "label": "england"
            },
            "Scotland": {
                "file": $('#uk_states').load('scotland-cities.html'),
                "label": "scotland"
            },
            //...

let county = city[$('#Uk_Cities option:selected').text()];
let countryCity = `${county.file} ${county.label}`;
```

I think that the issue might be coming from the `let county = city([$('#Uk_Cities option:selected').text()]);`

I don't know if I am placing the switch(county) properly when I convert to the object literal and in the dictionary of city types.

Can you guys help me out, please?

Many Thanks.

```js
let county = $('#Uk_Cities option:selected').text();
        switch (county) {
            case 'England':
                $('#uk_states').load('england-cities.html');
                break;
            case 'Scotland':
                $('#uk_states').load('scotland-cities.html');
                break;
            case 'Wales':
                $('#uk_states').load('wales-cities.html');
                break;
            case 'Northern Ireland':
                $('#uk_states').load('nireland-cities.html');
                break;
            default:
        }
    });
    $('#uk_states').change(function () {
        let stateSelected = $(this).val();
        let responseStatus = 'success';
        getTheWeatherData(stateSelected);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the inputs and outputs in an object and then look up the proper output from that object.

```js
// Store the input and output in an object
let locations = {
  England:"england",
  Scotland:"scotland",
  Wales:"wales",
  "Northern Ireland":"nireland"
};

let county = $('#Uk_Cities option:selected').text();

// Just load the correct document by building the string based on 
// looking up the key in the object
$('#uk_states').load(locations[county] + '-cities.html');

$('#uk_states').change(function () {
   let stateSelected = $(this).val();
   let responseStatus = 'success';
   getTheWeatherData(stateSelected);
});
```